# ClassList contains of elements child

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parent-child, contains

I know that this code is wrong, I am just unsure of how to fix it. 
Basically what I am trying to achieve is that if `wrapper`'s child has a class name `schooner` then a certain function will run. I will have many of these however all of the parents are named `wrapper`.

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper').length; i++) {
    if document.getElementsByClassName('wrapper')[i].firstChild.classList.contains('schooner') {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}
```

Comment: **Not the answer:** You should not keep using `document.getElementsByClassName` Store the result in a variable and reference the HTMLCollection. Every time you are calling it in the loop, it needs to query the DOM so it is slow. **The issue** I see is your if statement is not valid JavaScript. Missing parenthesis. The console should have the error message.

Comment: don't you miss some paranthesis for the if? `if(document.getEl....)`

Comment: @Sepultura that is correct, thats the issue I am having, thank you

Comment: And the easiest way to get the elements... `var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper > .schooner");`

Answer (score 0):

i would try jquery like this :

`$(".wrapper").each(function(){ 
        if($(this).first().contains('schooner')){ 
            console.log('hello') 
          } 
   });`